# Cannot read property 'input' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, undefined

I have a function that get's the user's input. Inside that function, is a callback function that checks the user's input. When calling the call back function, i get an error, ERROR Error: Cannot read property 'input' of undefined.

HTML

```
<input id="answer" type="number" (input)= "getInput($event, checkAnswer)" >
```

JS

```
input = null;
answer = null;


getInput(event, chkAns){

this.input = Number(event.target.value);

chkAns();

console.log("Input :" + " " + this.input);

 }

 checkAnswer(){

  if(this.input === this.answer){
  
    this.multiply();

  } else{

     console.log(this.input + " " + "is incorrect" + " "  + typeof 
     this.answer);
  }
    
}
```

Comment: Probably because `this` is undefined in that context.

Comment: Can you put a working snippet into your question - in particular to show how is getInput called and the relationship between chkAns and checkAnswer.

Comment: @AHaworth  Link: https://app-x.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of three things:

1. Make the function you pass (chkAns) atomic - that is, that it doesnt require a specific state (this.input, this.answer), and get those parameters when its called (so instead of `chkAns()`, you will do `chkAns(this.input, this.answer)`
2. Don't pass it from the template, but call `this.CheckAnswer()` inside `getInput`
3. Pass `this` contex to the chkAns when calling it: `chkAns.call(this)` - I think this option is the least "angularish" option

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/app-x-grpcsu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) of the **second** option